# vtiger upgrade from 7.0.1 to 7.1.0 causing illegal request

Tags: vtigercrm

If I try to upgrade vtiger, I am getting an illegal request message, nothing happens, any Idea whats going wrong?

[image: standard upgrade procedur]

[image: getting illegal request message]

Comment: on a different browser i am running into  ERROR EXTRACTING MIGRATION ZIP FILE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if $site_URL Variable is correct in config.inc.php file?
also you can disable this error by editing the following file 
includes/http/Request.php

around line 207-207 on validateReferer function find

```
        throw new Exception('Illegal request');
```

change to

```
        //throw new Exception('Illegal request');
```