# Vtiger - Get error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in https

Tags: https, vtiger

I used **CloudClare** to provide https connection, It points the domain to my server.
When I access through https, the browser says `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

I already set the config as following:

```
$dbconfigoption['ssl'] = true;
$site_URL = 'https://domain';
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error a few months ago. It turned out that my vtiger server was getting http and not https requests. It had to do with how the ssl certificate was installed. It was installed on a different server (a router?) on the same network as the vtiger server, which got the request did the decryption and passed it to the vtiger server as an http request. The vtiger server would see an http request and would send a redirect response to the configured https url. When the browser gets the redirect you end up in a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $site_URL with following value

```
$site_URL = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on' ? 'https': 'http')."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != '/' && dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != '\\' ? str_replace('\\','/',dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) : '').'/';
```

Comment: It allows me to access the page, but then shows the message 'Illegal request' everywhere :( I'm testing with ngrok to my local CRM at https://<ngrok-domain>/vtiger/

Comment: [Please check the following Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043576/vtiger-upgrade-from-7-0-1-to-7-1-0-causing-illegal-request/51269819#51269819)

Comment: @haimit, Not related to that issue. My CRM was working correctly before making change with your suggestion :)